# How to override New Tab page on Chrome (without 3rd party software, eg. extensions)

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to make my own new tab page, and replace the old new tab page with it. This could be done by simple replacing the default new tab, or by redirecting to a specific page when opening a new tab.

I'm looking for a way to do this without installing any extensions, because my employer blocks any purchases/installations from the Chrome Webstore.

Comment: Normally I'd say look in `about:flags` (the closest thing to Firefox's `about:config`) but it doesn't seem to have anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been asked a while ago but [I just found this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) which means that you can now override some Google default pages.

You have to do it with an extension whose manifest file will contains:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "pageToOverride": "myPage.html"
  },
```

where `pageToOverride` can be

- bookmarks
- history
- newtab

It is also said that you can customize it with CSS and JS (hopefully) but I have no idea on how Google's data are shared (if it's possible at all) for the bookmarks case.

There's no example on Google developer's website yet, and as I just found this I was looking for examples and ended up here.